# How to update a row using the Gspread python module

Tags: python-3.x, gspread

Hello basicaly i have this data, compose of name, project, reason and timestamps here's below is the structure

```
['John Doe', 'Hollywood', 'Good-time', '2022-05-17 15:25:45']
```

and on the documentation, it only shows how to update an individual cell, but i wanted to update entire row. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your showing value of `['John Doe', 'Hollywood', 'Good-time', '2022-05-17 15:25:45']` and `i wanted to update entire row.`?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 ways to update the content of you spreadsheet using gspread.

1. Using `update` method
   It will update the specified range with values you provide.
   Example: updating cells A2 to B2

```py
worksheet.update("A2:B2", [[42], [43]])
```

2. Using `update_cells`
   You create a list of `Cell` object with each value for each cell then update the cells

Examples: updating cells A2 to B2

```py
C1 = Cell(2, 1, 42)
C2 = Cell(2, 2, 43)
worksheet.update_cells([C1, C2])
```

Comment: the update_cells method was what I was searching for. However you may need to declare the Cell class in the beginning if you get an error -  from gspread import Cell

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answer by @Lavigne958 but I kept getting API error code 400.
I did this and I figured, it works, so I'll just share it here.

```py
worksheet.update("A2",[['John Doe', 'Hollywood', 'Good-time', '2022-05-17 15:25:45']])
```

`2` in `A2` being the row you want to edit.
`A2` is basically where you want to start modifying the values
Take note that the second argument has to be in the for of type `list(list(...))` where the outer list is 1 row, and the inner list is each column.

**NOTE**
[in **version 6.0.0 of gspread**]: method signature will change to: `Worksheet.update(value = [[]], range_name=)` arguments `range_name` and `values` will swap, values will be mandatory of type: `list(list(...))`

By the way, I'm using gspread 5.11.3 if anyone is interested.